# threading in python no errors but not work

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, python-requests, python-multithreading

i write a program to scrape data from website using requests and tkinter
there are start butoon that call Start_collecting_data function and it work good
i tried to add thread to my code to work faster so i changed command in start button to call threading_system function. the code give me no responce after add thread to threads list

```
 def threading_system(self):
        print('start threading')
        self.threads = []
        for i in range(100):   
            print(f'add thread number {i}')
            i = threading.Thread(target=self.Start_collecting_data)
            print('thread added')
            i.start()
            print('thread start')
            self.threads.append(i)
            print('thread append')
        for thread2 in self.threads:
            print('start joining')
            thread2.join()
            print('thread join')

        print('end of function')
```

all {for loops} work correctly and print all strings, except the last line {print('end of function')} not be printed

Comment: Does the function `self.Start_collecting_data` ever exit? If not, `thread2.join()` will wait forever.

Comment: Then it's time to run through the [MCVE] exercise. Reduce the number of threads to just two. Does your program finish? If not, reduce it to one. Does it finish? If not, now you can properly debug because you only have a single thread to check up on. And while you do that, show the output log. Are those joins actually happening?

Comment: self.Start_collecting_data have limited function and stop at the end
i reduced number of threads to 1 thread and also not work